# Vue.js seems to be reverting my list sort

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rubaxa-sortable

I am trying to re-order a list in vue.js component. After I complete the dragndrop, the order of the list goes a little *wonky* and no longer matches the actual order of the data that can be seen when performing the api call or when using the chrome vue.js extension. However the ending `console.log` does show the data in the desired order.

Below is the code that uses the RubaXa/Sortable lib.

```
export default {
  watch: {
    workout() {
      let list = this.workout.exercises
      Sortable.create(document.getElementById("exercises"), {
        onUpdate: e => {
          list.splice(e.newIndex, 0, list.splice(e.oldIndex, 1)[0])
          console.log(list.map(e => { console.log(e.details) }))
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the order was getting mixed was that I forgot to bind the `key`.

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
```